# Reflection. Execution constructor

Tags: java, android, reflection

I need to execute some method via reflection

method to execute

```
public void someMethod(int value1, int value2, String str, int value3)
{
    try
    {
        // some code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is execution code

```
public static void execute()
{
    try
    {
        String          className = "some.class";
        String          classPath = "some.pack.name" + ":" + "some.class";
        PathClassLoader loader    = new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(classPath, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

        Class           clazz     = Class.forName(className, true, loader);
        Method          method    = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class, Integer.TYPE); 
        Object          object    = clazz.newInstance();

        method.invoke(object, 1, 2, "str", 3);
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

But I gets error

```
    java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class someClass; no empty constructor
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
```

After that I inspected constructors for `someClass` and got this

```
someClass(android.content.Context,com.android.internal.someClass)
GenericParameterType 0 - class android.content.Context
GenericParameterType 1 - interface com.android.internal.someClass.someService
```

The question is: how to execute someMethod with given parameters and given generic types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create new instance when there is a parametrized constructor, you need to get constructor first and then call `newInstance()` with parameters on it.

If you have a class which constructor has two parameters of types `Context` and `SomeClass`, then instantiation of this class will look like this.

```
Object object = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class, SomeClass.class)
                          .newInstance(context, someClass);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I forgot: second parameter is service. Now I don't know hoe to set second parameter

Answer (score 1):

You need to create no-arg constructor in same class (SomeClass) as:

```
public SomeClass()
  {
  }
```